# how to write regular expression for e.g. [1,5,8-12,21-30, 35-*]

Tags: c#, regex

I have to write RegEx in C# to get

MaxUpperLimit = 70;

- User can enter multiple values with , seprated

  e.g. `10,20,30,35-40,45,50-55 //Valid`
- User can enter multiple values - seprated

  e.g. `10,20-30,35-40 //Valid`
- User can add Max limit variabble value

  e.g. `10,20-30,35-40,71-MaxUpperLimit  //Invalid`
     e.g. `10,20-30,35-40,50-MaxUpperLimit  //Valid`
- user can not enter any value more than MaxUppLimit

  e.g. `45-71 //Invalid`

Comment: Yep, you have to write. What did you try so far?

Comment: You could just split your input string by ',' and '-' and cast them to int to verify if they are smaller than 70.

Answer (score 4):

While a regex would possibly work well for just numbers, the `MaxUpperLimit` complicates things enough that it's probably more suitable for a parser.

The idea would be to simply split the string into components using `,` as a separator, that will get you something like the array of strings (call this step 1):

```
10
20
30
35-40
45
50-55
```

Then, for each of those, step 2 first modifies the string (into a proper range rather than a single value) if it doesn't yet have a `-` character, so that you end up with:

```
10-10
20-20
30-30
35-40
45-45
50-55
```

Then, for each of those do a further split (step 3) using `-`. That will give you either a 2 or 3-or-more element array with the latter being invalid (because they were malformed ones like `1-7-11`).

Then, for step 4, you check *those* array values (there are always two at this point due to checks performed previously) to check if any are the string `MaxUpperLimit`. If they are, just convert them to the proper value, in your case the string `"70"`.

For step 5, you just validate that they're numeric and also check that the ranges are valid as well. This involves both ensuring that the second value is greater than or equal to the first, and possibly that the first is greater than or equal to the second of the *previous* range, if you want to ensure you aren't allowing something like:

```
10-15,13-25
```

---

So, taking your examples one at a time, the first:

```
10,20,30,35-40,45,50-55 // Valid
Step 1: (10)        (20)        (30)        (35-40)     (45)        (50-55)
Step 2: (10-10)     (20-20)     (30-30)     (35-40)     (45-45)     (50-55)
Step 3: ((10) (10)) ((20) (20)) ((30) (30)) ((35) (40)) ((45) (45)) ((50) (55))
Step 4: no change
Step 5: all valid
```

The second one is covered by the exact same process as the first.

The third works well also, right up until step 5. Step 4 converts `((71) (MaxUpperLimit))` into `((71) (70))` and then the step 5 validation fails because the second value is less than the first.

This is not the case in your fourth example since `((50) (MaxUpperLimit))` becomes `((50) (70)` which is a valid range.

Similarly, the `45-71` in your fifth example would not validate because the number `71` is outside the allowable values.

---

In pseudo-code, what you're looking for is something like the following. First some code which checks that a single, fully specified range is valid.

```
def isValidRange (strarray, prevupper):
    lower = int(strarray[0])
    upper = int(strarray[1])
    if lower < 1 or upper > MaxUpperLimit:
        return false
    if lower > upper or lower < prevupper:
        return false
    return true
```

Next, the steps as detailed above:

```
def isValidRangeList(str):
    # Step 1

    strarray1 = str.split(",")

    prevupper = -1
    for each item in strarray1:
        # Step 2

        if not item.contains("-"):
            item = item + "-" + item

        # Step 3

        strarray2 = item.split("-")
        if strarray2.length() > 2:
            return false

        # Step 4

        if strarray2[0] == "MaxUpperLimit":
            strarray2[0] = MaxUpperLimit
        if strarray2[1] == "MaxUpperLimit":
            strarray2[1] = MaxUpperLimit

        # Step 5

        if not isValidRange( strarray2, prevupper):
            return false
        prevupper = int(strarray2[0])

    return true
```

Of course, that pseudo-code just validates the input data (and it's untested other than in my own head, so you may need some debugging). No doubt you'll find it useful to add the ranges to a structure collection in order to *use* them afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

I saw this as a challenge but you should really try something next time.

So here's a full regex solution with the `m` modifier:

```
^
  (?:
     (?:[0-6]?\d|70)(?:-[0-6]?\d|70)?
  )
  (?:
     ,(?:[0-6]?\d|70)(?:-[0-6]?\d|70)?
  )*
$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` : begin of line.
- `(?:` : group but don't capture.

  - `(?:` : group but don't capture.
  - `[0-6]?\d|70` : Match 00 until number 70
  - `(?:-[0-6]?\d|70)?` : Match `-` followed by a number from 00 until number 70, this is optional
- `)` : closing group
- `(?:,(?:[0-6]?\d|70)(?:-[0-6]?\d|70)?)*`: Match `,` followed by what I explained above, all 0 or more times
- `$` : end of line
- `m modifier` : make `^` and `$` match start and end of line respectively

**[Online demo](http://regex101.com/r/kU2kD7)**

**Note:** This won't take in account logical order, for example `70-50` is matched.

Comment: It also doesn't allow the `MaxUpperLimit` string but that's the price you pay for using regex instead of a parser. And thanks for the permission though I don't usually wait for it before downvoting :-) However, I'm always circumspect about downvoting answers unless they're _particularly_ horrible, which this one isn't.

Comment: @paxdiablo Well if the OP has a fixed limit he could change the regex accordingly. About the downvotes: Sometimes I find problems here on SO that people directly says "NO it's not possible using regex" for example parsing html with regex. While I know that this kind of problem should be used with a proper parser, I tend to show that Regex is capable of doing things more than people are aware of. I'm fully aware it isn't the ultimate and best choice thought :) Ah and I feel somehow bad since I vote closed this question and afterwards thought of solving it :p

Comment: Nice efforts, thank you very much for your answer. why this is showing **invalid**? `40-50,1234-4567` if i modified `70` to `5000` in regex formula

Comment: @imdadhusen that's totally expected. If you want to change the upperlimit, you have to edit the regex. So here's an [example](http://regex101.com/r/eC0pZ0) for limit=5000, basically you need to know the basics of regex and you'll be able to edit the upperlimit by yourself.

Answer (score 0):

To Check if the limit is too high:
           int MaxUpperLimit = 70;
            string input = "10,20-30,35-40,710-MaxUpperLimit";

```
        input = input.Replace("MaxUpperLimit", MaxUpperLimit.ToString());

        bool isLimitExceeded = false;
        int result = 0;

        foreach (var komma in input.Split(",".ToCharArray()))
        {
            if (komma.Contains("-"))
            {
                foreach (var minus in komma.Split("-".ToCharArray()))
                {
                    if (!Int32.TryParse(minus, out result) || result > MaxUpperLimit)
                    {
                        isLimitExceeded = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                if (!Int32.TryParse(komma, out result) || result > MaxUpperLimit || isLimitExceeded)
                {
                    isLimitExceeded = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
bool valid = str.Replace("MaxUpperLimit", MaxUpperLimit).Split(',').Select(p => p
                                     .Split('-')
                                     .Select(s=>s.Trim()).ToArray())
            .All(subPart => {
                    int i1, i2;
                    return (subPart.Length == 1 && int.TryParse(subPart[0], out i1) && i1 <= MaxUpperLimit) 
                    || (subPart.Length == 2 
                            && int.TryParse(subPart[0], out i1) && i1 < MaxUpperLimit 
                            && int.TryParse(subPart[1], out i2) && i2 <= MaxUpperLimit 
                            && i1 < i2);
                });
```